# Как получить список роутов?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Такой вопрос:
Можно ли в Nuxt.js каким то образом получить список всех текущий страниц на проекте?
 + Каким образом Nuxt.js ориентируется, где показывать 404-ю ошибку а где нет?
 (на какие данные он опирается при этом?)

Comment: Насчет nuxt не скажу, но во Vue можно только экспортировать массив роутов. В смысле, что в рантайме этот список ниоткуда больше не доступен.

Comment: А как конкретно например в Vue я могу запросить этот список?
Можно ли это сделать из компонента?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Он недоступен. Я же говорю, только если вы экспортируете этот список из роутера, и импортируете его вручную в компонент.

Comment: И при этом это просто будет обычный массив объектов, точно такой же, как в самом роутере, еще никак не модифицированный. Нужно получить `normalizedTo` - придется сначала найти нужный роут в этом списке (методы поиска могу описать), потом его зарезолвить, а потом уже обращаться ко свойствам этого зарезолвленного роута.

Comment: Методы мне бы пригодились если бы я понял как все это дело применить именно в nuxt.js )

Comment: С накстом не помогу, к сожалению. Не знаю специфику его. Зато уверен на 90%, что основное изменение в наксте по сравнению с Vue - это именно работа с роутером. Так что, тут уже лучше сами :)